# AngularJS increment day in date format

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What I'm doing is a small prototype application that interact with input date type format.

`<label>From:<input type="date" ng-model="window.from">`

What I did now is that if I change the date on the input a div get his width long n. pixel based on day.

Ie: if date is: `"2013-12-30"` the div will be width `30px`.

Now I would like to invert things using a `resize` plugin. If I resize the `div` to `20px` I would like my input to change in `"2013-12-20"`.

I'm trying different things, like split the date (`date.split("-")[2]`), increment and building back the date format... it work but I'm sure there is a better way to do that with js or better with angular...

I would like to know best practice to manage date type format with Angular if possible.

Comment: [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) is a really cool library to handle dates.

Comment: did you try `date.setDate()`?

Comment: If the date is `12-1-2013` do you want it to be 1px wide?

Answer (score 0):

I thought the string format could be possibile with some configuration of AngularJS date input type, but I was wrong, so I did a quick search.
I found two possibile solutions:

1. using Moment.js with [this module](https://github.com/dalelotts/angular-date-time-input)
2. check the answer of @scalaGirl to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18768714/angularjs-directive-to-modify-input-formatting) (but be careful, since her linked plunker is broken. Here is a [working fork](http://plnkr.co/edit/gOud60?p=preview))